# How do you conduct multiple queries and send all data to a template for rendering in a single res.render?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database called Critterpedia that contains 3 collections: fish, bugs, sea creatures. I am trying to query those collections to render the critters that will be leaving this month. Below is my fish collection query that works and renders. How do I conduct the same query for the other two collections but send all the data at once with a single res.render() call?

```
app.get('/critters', (req, res) => {
    let query = {$and: [{fishMonthsNorth: thisMonth}, {fishMonthsNorth: {$ne: nextMonth}}]}
     
    //Find all fish that leave this month
    Fish.find(query, (err, thisMonthFish) => {
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('index', {thisMonthFish : thisMonthFish});
        }
    }); 
});
```

Ideally I would like to:

```
//Query fish collection
//Query Bugs collection
//Query Sea collection
//res.render('index', {fish : fish, bugs : bugs, sea : sea});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have add an answer to your question, please add your reaction to it, will it help you or not. And up vote if it provide a useful information or accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pretty easy, you wouldn't even believe.

Instead of writing a huge `Model.aggregation` query with `$merge` and `$lookups`, you could make 3 `.find` at once (*in parallel*), via [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or [`for await of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/**
 * Model importing / Collections
 */

const fish_db = require("../../db/fish_db");
const bug_db = require("../../db/bug_db");
const sea_db = require("../../db/sea_db");

router.get('/critters', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        let response = {};
        /**
        * You could form / pre-determine more queries, for each of your collection
        */
        let query = {$and: [{fishMonthsNorth: thisMonth}, {fishMonthsNorth: {$ne: nextMonth}}]};
        /**
        * Promise.allSettled is ES2020 feature, you could use Promise.all instead
        * or for await of arrayOfPromises
        */
        await Promise.allSettled([
           fish_db.find(query).then(docs => { Object.assign(response, {fish: docs}) } )
           bug_db.find(query).then(docs => { Object.assign(response, {bug: docs}) } )
           sea_db.find(query).then(docs => { Object.assign(response, {sea: docs}) } )
        ])
        /** You could add almost anything to response if you want it to */
        await res.status(200).json(response);
    } catch (e) {
        await res.status(404).json(e);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

You could also form your array of promises before, like:

```
let futureFinds = [];

if (need to search for fish) {
    futureFinds.push(await fish_db.find(query))
}

if (need to search for bugs) {
    futureFinds.push(await bugs_db.find(query))
}

const [result_one, result_two] = await Promise.all(futureFinds)
```

and then handle them at-once as you see in code above.

Comment: Thank you for your response and taking the type to write this up! I am still learning and am doing this project as a learning environment. To be honest, a lot of it is over my head but I'm trying to break it down. Is the res.status(200).json(response) call the data that gets sent? I am using an EJS template for rendering and am trying to figure out what I would use to breakdown that JSON object for rendering to the browser.

```<%= response.fish.name %>```
```<%= response.bug.location %>```
etc.

Comment: `response` is the object what you wanted to see with `{fish : fish, bugs : bugs, sea : sea}` you could check if yourself, via `console.log(responce)` adding this string before `res.status(200)` and watch for server console.

Comment: @MattMiller also, if you want to `res.send` a `EJS` template, you could pre-add, before `res` event will be complited. (If it doesn't added somehow), but tbh, it's better to separate front-end pages, and back-end logic. And make an API for it.

Comment: There is actually an API that I used to get the data. To further learn Mongo/mongoose, I wrote a script that pulled the data from the API and put it into a database for me. That's what I have been working with and am now realizing it may have been a mistake to do it this way.

Comment: @MattMiller according to Express documentation (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) you should pass your file and object like in example: `res.render('user', { name: 'Tobi' }, function (err, html) {...}`